# How to create complex user roles in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am looking at creating a set of permission roles based on groups and then filtering the data they see from the datasources based on those role specifics, but I cannot seem to get it to go forward as I would like.

To get proof of concept I am only trying to filter down a roster datasource and have the following server-side script:

```
function roleCheckAgents(user)
{
  var userRoles = app.getActiveUserRoles();
  var query = app.models.Agents.newQuery();

  if(userRoles.indexOf(app.roles.testRole) >= 1){
     if(app.models.Agents.getRecords().filter().
       query.filters.strRelatedCompany._equals === "sampleCompany");
     return query.run();
  }

}
```

the group itself has mine and a few other emails in it, and is listed as `testRole`.  In the Agents datasource security, I have Load listed as script with: `roleCheckAgents(user)`.

Realistically, I would like to set multiple filters within one role, e.g. `Company === "sampleCompany" && Site === "sampleSite"`, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I currently can't see how this will function the way I need/want.

Thank you!

**Update:**

I was able to get the multiple filters to work, but only as a query script of the datasource.  The problem that created is that I already had query builder conditions within the section and you can only have query builder or query script.

Query Script works as follows:

```
var query = app.models.Audits.newQuery();  
if(app.getActiveUserRoles().indexOf(app.roles.Test) > -1)
  {   query.filters.field1._contains = "center";
      query.filters.field2._contains = "status";
      return query.run();}
else
{}
```

The current query builder items were:

```
field1 contains? :searchText OR
field2 contains? :searchText OR
field3 contains? :searchText OR
field4 contains? :searchText OR
field5 contains? :searchText
```

Any thoughts on how to have both as part of either the query builder or the query script?

Thank you.
Kristopher

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use "Model Permissions" where you specify each role's access (security tab on a datasource). You can create custom roles if you're GCP Super Admin.